# findViewById returns null for existing included layout

Tags: android, layout, view

in my main layout (set in on create) i have some included layout which have a `imageview` in them. Some where in my code I need to set bitmap to these imageViews. My method is this:

```
(ImageView) ((findViewById(R.id.first_app + (i - 1)).findViewById(R.id.app_image)));
```

which I is loop variable. **Problem is I get null for findViewById(R.id.first_app + (i - 1) but these layouts exist in main layout.**

please help me finding the cause of this error. I'm really confused and I'm near deadline.
here is My main layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3"
    tools:context=".MoreAppsActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/more_app_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:background="#EA7026">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/more_app_title_img"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
            android:src="@drawable/more_app_title_image"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/first_app"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/single_app_layout" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/second_app"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/single_app_layout" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/third_app"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/single_app_layout" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/more_app_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:background="#DBBE00">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/more_app_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
            android:src="@drawable/more_app_threecircle"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_below="@id/more_app_button"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="?????? ??? ?????"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and included layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/app_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/app_text_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/app_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:background="#88000000"
            android:text="aligholi salavat"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe I don't know something that you know, but what are you trying to do with findViewById(R.id.xyz+(i-1)) ?

Comment: R.id is an integer. Since my included layout are sequential, their ids are sequential two. (difference is one). I use this in loop for preventing code redundancy.

Comment: @alireza : R.id might resolve to integers but `R.id.first_app` (for example) is actually just the name of a `static final` field in the `R.java` class file. You cannot treat it like a string and just append numbers.

Comment: @Squonk: actually I get correct result some days ago when my app was small. I  replaced included layouts with frame layouts and give them unique id but still i get null exception.
It seems the main layout hasn't created properly.

Comment: @alireza : My point is...don't do this. The R.java file is auto-generated and the integers assigned to any resource id can change at any time. You can not trust the code you are trying to use will get the resource that you expect.

Comment: I've changed that but still get the same result

Answer (score 1):

the issue is

```
findViewById(R.id.first_app + (i - 1))
```

Basically, R.id.first_app is a reference to an int in the R file, you cannot append numbers to it because it will end up equaling a reference to something else. There is every chance that they will change order or value when compiling.

Edit: You could create an int array of R.id.first_app, R.id.second_app and R.id.third_app. This way the pointers to the layouts remain constant.

```
int[] layouts = {R.id.first_app, R.id.second_app, R.id.third_app};
```

Then in the loop

```
findViewById(layouts[i])
```

Comment: Your are right but since it doesn't solve my question, I can not mark it as answer.

Comment: I worked on my code and find that there is no error on finding text views and error only occurs for ImageViews! Have you any idea what's the problem?